# Cannot integrate AppImage with appimagelauncher in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, appimage

Newbie here. I am in need to integrate software released in AppImage form to my Kubuntu 20.04 system.
For that I always used appimagelauncher, which worked like a charm until when I tried to integrate another software. Last time it worked was about a year ago.
Now, when launched, appimagelauncher tells me 'Failed to move AppImage to target location.
Try to copy AppImage instead?'
If I answer Yes, I get 'Failed to copy AppImage to target location'.

Any idea of what is now happening? Perhaps appimagelauncher does no longer have authority to write on the disk?

Thanks

Darknice

Update: i am trying to install appimaged, but it tells me to uninstall appimagelauncher first (which is already removed (with purge)).

This is really driving me nuts, since it seems that something is left running by appimagelauncher.

Comment: You appear to have a problem with the target folder, by default ~/Applications

Comment: I figured that, but the target folder is available, I can transfer files to it via Dolphin without issues and doesn't seem to have issues. I tried to remove (with purge) appimagelauncher and re-install it from the team PPA, but with the same result. FYI, I am integrating the appimage files from another SSD drive in my laptop. This may have started since I replaced the HD with a SSD on it, but I am not sure. Also, I am not able to change the settings in appimagelauncher.. Is there an alternative GUI?

Comment: Would it work if you first moved the app image in a folder under your home folder? Just to check whether the issue is with the current location of the appimage.

Comment: I already tried that, by placing an appimage in the Download folder, but no dice. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem. For me, the issue was that I had manually created a menu item that launched an .AppImage file -- I believe before I had actually installed `appimagelauncherd`, if that's possible.

The menu item itself was a file like `~/.local/share/applications/MyApp.desktop` and it was pointing to `/opt/MyApp.AppImage`.

When AppImageLauncherd was trying to "integrate" that file, I believe it was attempting to move (i.e. remove) the `/opt/MyApp.AppImage` file, and finding that it couldn't -- I assume because that's the file I was executing, so it was protected. I let AppImageLauncherd "copy" it instead of "moving" it, and it created a second .Desktop file that appeared in my menu.

All I did was delete the original `/opt/MyApp.AppImage` file and associated `.Desktop` file, and use only the newly-created one, and my problem is solved.